# Logitech bluetooth notebook mouse replacement

Tags: logitech-mouse

My long serving Logitech V200 notebook mouse is dying and I think it is finally time to look for a replacement.

[image: link text]

I am aware of this question https://superuser.com/questions/2198/mouse-recommendation which is asking for a gaming mouse recommendation however my requirements are different.

The mouse I currently use is a smaller "notebook" style bluetooth mouse that works "driverless" with Mac OS X and Windows.

I was thinking of possibly a [Microsoft presenter mouse](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/Presenter/productdetails.aspx?pid=085), as the next one.

Thoughts? Recommendations ?

Comment: What's a mouse? Stick to touchpad!

Comment: Unfortunately MonoDevelop only right clicks with a mouse, not the touchpad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have very good experience with MS hardware.

And you answered to your question :)

Wireless Notebook Presenter Mouse 8000 is good choice.

[Here is list Bluetooth mouse from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/ProductList.aspx?type=Mouse&techId=Bluetooth)

Answer (score 1):

I like the [V450 Nano](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/mice_pointers/mice/devices/4335&cl=us,en). So much I bought three of them (One for work, one for home, one for a friend.) This mouse fits my slightly smaller hands perfectly, plus it's got the nano receiver that you can just plug into your notebook and forget about! It takes two standard AA batteries, and they last a long time.

I also have the [VX Nano](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/mice_pointers/mice/devices/3271&cl=US,EN), but that one is actually a little too small and I don't like the fact you cannot click the scroll wheel for middle click. Instead, it changes the wheel from normal mode to "free spin" mode. Middle click has been relegated to a small button behind the wheel. I found I don't really used the "free spin" mode very often (PgUp, PgDn, Ctrl+[Home/End] are your friends.) Also Vista apps couldn't really keep up with the "free spin" mode for me, so it didn't work well. But I use middle click *all* the time. The VX Nano takes two AAA batteries.

Answer (score 0):

This mouse is by far the best one I have ever used!!!  I like it so much I had to buy one for every computer I own.  I can't tell you the hardship having to go back to a normal mouse after using one of these.  One very nice feature is the flywheel scroll wheel. When navigating large spreadsheets or long documents, the wheel will spin freely for a full 7 seconds.  This will keep you from wearing your finger out doing these kinds of things.  It also has the smallest receiver I have seen on any mouse.

http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/mice_pointers/mice/devices/3271&cl=US,EN

Comment: I also have this mouse, but I don't like the fact you cannot click the scroll wheel for middle click. Instead, it changes the wheel from normal mode to "free spin" mode. Middle click has been relegated to a small button behind the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [RadTech Bluetooth Mice](http://www.radtech.us/Products/Bluetooth/). I'm using the BT600 for a while and I'm really happy with it. They have a standard mini-USB connector so you can charge them quite everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bluetooth, get a [Logitech v270](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BDH2Y8), or its replacement, the [v470](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UY3NR8). No dongle to worry about, just a mouse! It works with mac and windows very well. And the batteries are AAs, (and they last a long time), so you don't have to worry about charging batteries, or being stuck with a dead mouse.

I have 2, and I love them.